# Space-Between not working even after giving them each a div

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a space between the text and the buttons but nothing happens.
I tried "isolating" the text and both of the buttons inside a div (one for each group) but basically, nothing happens.

The CSS file :

```
.card {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -10%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.actions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

the React file :

```
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={classes.addtodo}>
        <AddTodo onAddHandler={onAddHandler} deleteAllTodos={deleteAllTodos} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className={classes.card}>
          {todos.map((todo) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <div className={classes.actions}>
                  <Todo name={todo.name} />
                  <button onClick={() => deleteTodoHandler(todo.id, todo.name)}>
                    X
                  </button>
                  <button onClick={() => setTodoEditing(todo.id)}>Edit</button>
                </div>

                {todoEditing === todo.id ? (
                  <form>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      onChange={(e) => setEditedText(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button onClick={() => editTodoHandler(todo.id)}>v</button>
                  </form>
                ) : (
                  <div></div>
                )}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Because your flex axis changed, justify-content does not work like it would if your flex axis was in row orientation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#the_main_axis

Comment: Perhaps you could show an image showing your intended layout versus what you have with the code you have supplied?